# is web.get_siteGroups() work with all site users including visitors

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to validate if the current user whiten specific group using JavaScript, but first i want to make sure is the following code work with all site users including visitors (read only permission):

```
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
        var groups = web.get_siteGroups();
        var group = groups.getByName("Managers");
        var groupUsers = group.get_users();

        context.load(user);
        context.load(groups);
        context.load(group);
        context.load(groupUsers);

        context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);

        function success(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var enumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var tempUser = enumerator.get_current();
                if (tempUser.get_id() == user.get_id()) {
                    //TODO
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        function failure(sender, args) {
        }
```

In another word, is the above code need any specific permeation to execute. as example, accessing information about all site groups is allow for read only permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each group has a setting which says who can view the group members. So if your group `Managers` has that setting set for all users then your code will work for all users.